# What is the tissue structure of bamboo?

Tags: botany

If the xylem and phloem of the bamboo is not in the hollow center than where is it located/situated? cannot get clear cut answers from the above discussions

Comment: Was this not answered in : https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/26123/what-does-the-empty-space-in-the-bamboo-stem-do

Comment: What above discussions? If this question has been asked before you cannot duplicate it.